# Is it possible in MySQL to select strings that contains part that are referenced in another column?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is an example, my "reference" is as follow:

1. | Zeus
2. | Poseidon
3. | Apollon

Then I've got this "to compare" table:

- Poseidon benediction
- Random benediction
- Power from Zeus

And what I want is some thing like this:

- Poseidon benediction | Poseidon
- Power from Zeus | Zeus

Is there a way to compare the content of the strings with the reference table ?

What I tried :

`WHERE ... IN (SELECT reference FROM referencetable)`
but this compare the whole string row so return nothing because it's not contained in the reference table

`WHERE ... LIKE CONCAT("%", (SELECT reference FROM referencetable), "%")` 
but this trhow and error because it work only for one reference value (error says thar ther is more than one row)

Is there a way to merge this 2 ideas to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` with `like`:

```
select t.*, c.*
from t1 join
     tocompare c
     on c.reference like concat('%', t1.col, '%');
```